# Javascript URIs injected into template at run-time do not render appropriate S3 backend URLs - all other injected admin URLs render accordingly

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, redactor

I'm using the package, "django-wysiwyg-redactor," for a blog entry interface within the admin application. When the admin site loads, the package injects a handful of source URLs for the JavaScript files it needs to render the rich text editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/redactor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/redactor/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/redactor/redactor.min.js"></script>
...and so on...
```

The project I'm working on is using the Boto backend to serve files from an S3 bucket. The URLs injected by Django to render the admin page render correctly, appending the proper S3 data to make the call to the bucket:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://siteName.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/js/jquery.min.js?Signature=signatureKeyGoesHere&amp;Expires=1454163206&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AWSAccessKeyIDGoesHere"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://siteName.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/js/jquery.init.js?Signature=signatureKeyGoesHere&amp;Expires=1454163206&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AWSAccessKeyIDGoesHere"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://siteName.s3.amazonaws.com/admin/js/actions.min.js?Signature=signatureKeyGoesHere&amp;Expires=1454163206&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AWSAccessKeyIDGoesHere"></script>
```

For some reason, the Redactor URLs don't render correctly -- appending the data necessary to make the call to the S3 bucket.
I had everything working fine during local development (while still using the remote file backend)

I also had everything working fine during my first deployment.

Just this evening I went to go mess around with the development branch site - which had the exact code base as the production (which was working during initial deployment) - and saw that the blog entry form was not rendering. I checked the in-browser javascript console and found the handful of resource load failure messages pertaining to the files Redactor uses:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://siteName.herokuapp.com/static/redactor/jquery.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    http://siteName.herokuapp.com/static/redactor/css/redactor.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://siteName.herokuapp.com/static/redactor/css/django_admin.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://siteName.herokuapp.com/static/redactor/jquery-migrate.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://siteName.herokuapp.com/static/redactor/redactor.min.js
```

As you can see, those URLs aren't in the same format as those listed above.

All necessary files are indeed present within the S3 bucket.

I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain how did you implement remote S3 storage? can you reach the 404'd links by pasting them in your browser? also, are the discrepancies between the code pieces intended? (siteName.s3.amazon.com vs. siteName.herokuapp.com, /static/ vs. /admin/js/)

Comment: `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`  
`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'`  


Cannot reach files via copy/paste as there are no such files on the root server.  

The discrepancies you mention are the links rendered by Boto to make the call to the S3 bucket. I did, however, modify the subdomain, signature and access ID within the URLs for privacy reasons.

Comment: have you uploaded the files manually or with `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Initially with collectstatic. The files are present within the bucket and in correct paths. After seeing this issue, I did attempt to manually upload the files to the bucket to see if that'd make any difference -- no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your STATIC_URL is set to use your bucket location.

```
STATIC_URL = "https://siteName.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

See also here:
[Serving Django's static and media files from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301200/serving-djangos-static-and-media-files-from-s3)

In general, redactor users the Django Form Media class. For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/